# How to prevent implicit generalization casts when using generic types in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

Minimal example:

```kotlin
fun <T> Iterable<T>.find2(elem: T) = this.find { it == elem }
```

Here, `T` is used to both denote the type of the `Iterable`, as well as the type of `elem`. It seems fine, however, a statement like this is syntactically correct, but doesn't make semantic sense:

```kotlin
listOf(1, 2, 3).find2("foo")
```

I assume this works because `T` resolves to `Any`.

I'm aware of the solution to explicitly state the type of the function:

```kotlin
listOf(1, 2, 3).find2<Int>("foo")
```

In this case, the compiler reports an incompatibility error, and rightfully so. However, this doesn't seem to be the solution, since it requires to explicitly declare the type, and will not report an error if forgotten (which makes bugs likely).

Is there a way to "constrict" the type `<T>`, so that, if, for example, the receiver is of type `Iterable<Int>`, the parameter must also be `Int`? In other words, is there a way to prevent the implicit cast to `Any`?

Comment: Here's the issue: in Kotlin, an `Iterable<Int>` is _also_, always, an `Iterable<Any>`.

Comment: It's not an implicit cast to `Any`, it's that `T` is resolved to whatever type is an ancestor of the `List` contents and the argument you pass. And this is something which very often one needs, imagine having a list containing some interface type and you looking for a concrete instance. You want `T` to be the common ancestor of the types involved.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
listOf(1, 2, 3).find2("foo")
```

There are actually two types that need to be resolved,
`T1` in `listOf<T1>` and `T2` in `Iterable<T2>.find2`,
and have the following constraints

- T1 is the same as T2, because `listOf` returns `List<T1>`, which is `Iterable<T2>`, for `find2`
- `1`, `2` and `3` should be assignable to `T1`
- `"foo"` should be assignable to `T2`

Therefore, the type has to be `Any`.

We usually explicitly declare the type of the list since it is the source,

```
listOf<Int>(1, 2, 3).find2("foo")
```

Or separate it into two statements

```
val listOfInt = listOf(1, 2, 3)
listOfInt.find2("foo")
```